# Using the JQuery .Ajax() method?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating a site where the user fills out a form, has that data sent to a php script and display result in a div and have been struggling to complete it for a while now. Below is the code i have created:

the button activates this function:

```
function callFunc()
{
    var testVar = "Example 01";
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "public/includes/userCreate.php",
        type: "POST",     
        data: testVar,  
        success: function(html) 
        {             
              $('#web_Content').html(html);
        }      
    });     
};
```

The PHP file is this:

```
<?php
    $test = $_POST['testVar'];
    echo $test;
?>
```

For some reason though i doesnt work. I mean it doesnt inject the value of the echo command into the div, If however i take out the variable data from the PHP and just have it echo a simple  element, it does work and injects the echo value into the div, Below is the code that will run:

```
<?php
    $test = $_POST['testVar'];
    echo "<h3>User ???? Created.</h3>";
?>
```

I think it is because i am not sending data correctly, Could anyone tell me the correct way to send the data to the PHP script and also, how to send more than one variable?

Comment: Have you tried `data: testVar.serialize(),`?

Answer (score 3):

you need `data: { testVar: "Example 01"}` it is a key value pair. This will generate a query string parameter like `testVar=Example%2001`

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to send data via the AJAX function is with either an object or string. Examples:

```
var pData = "testVar=Example.";
$.ajax({
/* Other ajax params */
data: pData,
/* Other ajax params */
});
```

or

```
var pData = { testVar: "Example." };
$.ajax({
/* Other ajax params */
data: pData,
/* Other ajax params */
});
```